# How to adapt gtk3 application, made with glade and python, to new screen size?

Tags: screen, gtk3

I developped an application on a 1920x1080 screen (Debian9 64bits GNOME) and by clicking on the border, it expand to the whole window (all good).
When I start the same application on another PC 1280x800 Debian9 32bit LXDE, the window is troncated at the bottom; by clicking at the window border, it dont adapt automatically to the screen size = it stay troncated at the bottom.
Know anybody what should be done in order to fit the application to any screen size where it is started?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_break_time">
    <property name="upper">5</property>
    <property name="value">5</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_minutes_time_correction">
    <property name="upper">15</property>
    <property name="value">15</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_penalty_duration">
    <property name="upper">45</property>
    <property name="value">45</property>
    <property name="step_increment">5</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_period">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">2</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_period_time">
    <property name="upper">15</property>
    <property name="value">15</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_points_left">
    <property name="upper">100</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_points_right">
    <property name="upper">100</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_seconds_time_correction">
    <property name="upper">60</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_time_penalty">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">2</property>
    <property name="value">2</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_timeout">
    <property name="upper">1</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">0.5</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_timeout_number_left">
    <property name="upper">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment_timeout_number_right">
    <property name="upper">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="scoreboard_window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">scoreboard uwr</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkNotebook">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="row_homogeneous">True</property>
            <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkBox">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkBox">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
                    <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkGrid">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="row_homogeneous">True</property>
                        <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkLabel">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                            <property name="label" translatable="yes">PERIOD:</property>
                          </object>
                          <packing>
                            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                          </packing>
                        </child>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton_period">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                            <property name="max_length">1</property>
                            <property name="width_chars">1</property>
                            <property name="max_width_chars">1</property>
                            <property name="xalign">0.5</property>
                            <property name="progress_pulse_step">1</property>
                            <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">1</property>
                            <property name="input_purpose">number</property>
                            <property name="adjustment">adjustment_period</property>
                            <property name="climb_rate">1</property>
                            <property name="numeric">True</property>
                            <property name="value">1</property>
                          </object>
                          <packing>
                            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                          </packing>
                        </child>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="expand">False</property>
                        <property name="fill">True</property>
                        <property name="position">0</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkGrid">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="row_homogeneous">True</property>
                        <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkGrid">
                            <property name="visible">True</property>
                            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                            <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton_timeout_left">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="max_length">1</property>
                                <property name="width_chars">1</property>
                                <property name="max_width_chars">1</property>
                                <property name="xalign">0.5</property>
                                <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">0</property>
                                <property name="input_purpose">number</property>
                                <property name="adjustment">adjustment_timeout_number_left</property>
                                <property name="numeric">True</property>
                              </object>
                              <packing>
                                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                              </packing>
                            </child>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton_timeout_right">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                                <property name="max_length">1</property>
                                <property name="width_chars">1</property>
                                <property name="max_width_chars">1</property>
                                <property name="xalign">0.5</property>
                                <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">0</property>
                                <property name="input_purpose">number</property>
                                <property name="adjustment">adjustment_timeout_number_right</property>
                                <property name="numeric">True</property>
```

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: the HTML file created by GLADE is 172000 characters big. It cannot be fully uploaded here (maximum 30000 characters). What extract of the code should be posted? (I think this is a question of parameters in GLADE). I posted an extract (beginning).

Comment: Could you create a simple example that illustrates your problem? I expect some widget constraint to be the problem, but without knowing exactly what you have, it's the blind leading the blind.